# Cannot change the innerHTML element

Tags: javascript

I want to change a button inside a td tag (see at the bottom an example).

```
var tableEntryButton = document.getElementById('slButton' + message.content[1])
```

delivers correctly the td element I am looking for:

```
<td id="slButtonAudi" data-value="false">
  <button id="slButtonActive" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" onclick="handleClickOnSSButton(this)">Start</button>
</td>
```

Here my function that should make the change possible.
Here I distinguish by the ID within the `button` tag what change I can apply (remove the current start/stop button and add the button with the opposite function)

```
var tableEntryButton = document.getElementById('slButton' + message.content[1])

let activeButton = '<button id="slButtonActive" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" onclick="handleClickOnSSButton(this)">Start</button>'
let inactiveButton = '<button id="slButtonInactive" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" type="button" onclick="handleClickOnSSButton(this)">Stop</button>'

if (tableEntryButton.innerHTML.includes('slButtonActive')) {
  tableEntryButton.removeChild(tableEntryButton.firstChild)
  tableEntryButton.innerHTML = inactiveButton
}
else {
  tableEntryButton.removeChild(tableEntryButton.firstChild)
  tableEntryButton.innerHTML = activeButton
}
```

The if/else allocation works correctly.

It appears that only the changes within the if/else statement are somehow not being applied.

**To clarify it here an example**.

**If this is given:**

```
<td id="slButtonAudi" data-value="false">
  <button id="slButtonActive" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" onclick="handleClickOnSSButton(this)">Start</button>
</td>
```

**it should be changed to that:**

```
<td id="slButtonAudi" data-value="false">
  <button id="slButtonInactive" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" type="button" onclick="handleClickOnSSButton(this)">Stop</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid it's not clear quite what's going on here or what the problem is Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if you have more than one table cell where you're doing this, you're producing an invalid document. `id` values **must** be unique in the document, they cannot be duplicated. (When you duplicate them, in general browsers will give you the first element with that `id` in the document when you use `getElementById`, but since the document is invalid, there's no guarantee that will be the case.)

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry if this was confusing. I did my best to improve my question. Let me know if something is still unclear. My problem is not related to any ID issues, its more that the found and correct element is just not replaced as it should be.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `removeChild` if you're setting the `innerHTML`; setting the `innerHTML` removes any children automatically. More importantly though, what calls the function that you've shown here?

Comment: May I suggest you simply toggle classes/id/text, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/4hdLexo5/1/

Comment: @LGSon ty for that. It helped to improve my JS skills!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the innerHtml correctly.

I made you an example that will do exactly what you asked in your last example.

```
if (tableEntryButton.innerHTML.includes('slButtonActive')) {
  //Get the children button.
  let button = tableEntryButton.querySelector("#slButtonActive");

  if (button) {
    tableEntryButton.removeChild(button);
    tableEntryButton.innerHTML += inactiveButton;
  }
}
```

Here is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vrtfoh9q/20/

Some documentation:
https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/append-or-prepend-to-an-element-29/
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can access children by children property in HTML element and use innerHTML once time like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
 <button id="btn1Active">Active</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let divTarget = document.getElementById('div1'), 
child = divTarget.children[0],
btnActive = '<button id="btn1Active">Active</button>',
btnInactive = '<button id="btn1Inactive">Inactive</button>'

if (child.id == 'btn1Active') divTarget.innerHTML = btnInactive
else divTarget.innerHTML = btnActive
```

**CodePen example**
https://codepen.io/bragamonte/pen/PBLojZ